# What is the slope of the sides of Aristarchus crater on the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science, scientific-data, topography

The question [If you fell into a crater on the moon in your spacesuit and no jetpack, is there a way to use low gravity to get out of the hole?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43648/12102) mentions [Aristarchus crater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristarchus_(crater)) as an example.

It's a pretty large crater and the sides will have complex topography. The image below is a Hubble Space Telescope image combined with topographical data from LRO from [Hubble Space Telescope Looks at the Moon to Prospect for Resources (Aristarchus Crater - gray)](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/details.cgi?aid=3275); "Simulated topography derived from Clementine data is used for relief"

Is it possible to find a topographical map for this crater, or some way to estimate the average sidewall slope?

[image: Hubble Space Telescope Looks at the Moon to Prospect for Resources (Aristarchus Crater - gray)]

Comment: It looks like you could walk out.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I didn't see a lot of *conventional stairs* in [Kim Holders' Moonwards videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCKqnm8TuN3dCO22kkNGyCIg/videos), I think vertical ascent may be tougher than it first seems, though we should limit that discussion to the linked question. There's this though: https://youtu.be/6eNjO8_VgYQ

Comment: https://sos.noaa.gov/datasets/moon-surface-slope/ almost certainly has it, but it's too late in the day for me to figure out the answer from it...

Comment: A quick look at a contour map shows 15 to 20 degree slope (beware exaggerated vertical scale in 'simulated' photo).

Comment: @amI thanks! Is it a "secret" contour map?

Comment: It is low-res so doesn't show the terraces in yzokras answer.  I am confused by long links: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FComparison-of-illumination-condition-over-Aristarchus-crater-a-comes-from-the_fig2_339452468&psig=AOvVaw3n7u22IATEzH_iEISv6kyJ&ust=1587839732068000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJCvxYragekCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI

Comment: @amI here's a shorter one with captions https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Comparison-of-illumination-condition-over-Aristarchus-crater-a-comes-from-the_fig2_339452468 from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/339452468_Lunar_Regolith_Temperature_Variation_in_the_Rumker_Region_Based_on_the_Real-Time_Illumination) and an *even shorter* one without https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifDfY.png I see what you mean now, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The slope is over 50 degrees at some point.

I made a quick pseudocolor rendering of the slope with QGIS using the [global DEM from LRO LOLA](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/details/Moon/LRO/LOLA/Lunar_LRO_LOLA_Global_LDEM_118m_Mar2014). The slope was generated from the DEM using QGIS's slope tool, after having cropped the global DEM. Some artifacts (the vertical bands) can be seen though.

Also, [Regional tiles from SLDEM2015](https://pgda.gsfc.nasa.gov/products/54) can be useful to not have to download 8 gigabytes.

[image: Slope at Aristachrus crater]

Another useful link: [NASA Moon Trek](https://trek.nasa.gov/moon) enables to compute the elevation profile over a path (but not the slope though).

Comment: Beautiful! It seems one would have to do some careful planning to find an easy path between top and bottom.

Comment: Wow! Very cool.